# How could I convert png binary data into bmp binary data in JAVA?

Tags: java, image, base64

I got my binary data from database which is in PNG format. Now, I need to change the format to BMP and then convert it to a string by Base64.

My logic is PNG binary-->BMP binary-->BMP base64 String.

My Code is as below. The input "data" is the PNG binary, imageFormat="BMP".

```
 public static String imageToBase64 (byte[] data, String imageFormat) throws IOException{
         BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
         ImageIO.write(imag, imageFormat, baos);

         String base64String=Base64.encodeBytes(baos.toByteArray());

         return base64String;        
     }
```

However, the result always return empty. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: After `ImageIO.write`, try flushing the stream; `baos.flush();`

Comment: I tried. Still get empty output.

Comment: How about omitting the size constraint? `new ByteArrayOutputStream();`

Comment: still not working

Comment: What are you using for an `imageFormat` string? [Is it one of the supported ones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getReaderFormatNames())? What is the return value of `ImageIO.write`? The method signature returns a boolean, what does your call return?

Comment: imageFormat="BMP". I also tried "jpg". None of them work. ImageIO.write return false.

Comment: Is it one of the supported formats? Use the above mentioned call to get supported formats. `false` means that [no writer was found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)) for the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Java API to write to a new BMP file. Based on your code this is how it does what you asked.

```
public static String imageToBase64(byte[] data, String imageFormat) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage imag = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
    BufferedImage bmpImg = new BufferedImage(imag.getWidth(), imag.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    bmpImg.createGraphics().drawImage(imag, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bmpImg, imageFormat, baos);
    String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
    return base64String;
}
```

Please note I used "bmp" (lowercase) instead of "BMP". Not sure if this matters. Enjoy.

Comment: Seems like it works. Thanks. One more question: Do I need to add baos.close() before return?

Comment: According to the Java API, close() does not have any effect on a ByteArrayOutputStream. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close()
So you don't really have to close it.

Comment: Thanks. I compared the base64-String before converting and base64-String after converting. Some weird result comes out. String before converting: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB9AAAAJYCAYAAAA6431rAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJzs3T12G2uWJdBTlU63lVFe......            String after converting:Qk227jYAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAA0AcAAFgCAAABABgAAAAAAIDuNgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////////////////////......                 Do you know why I will get so many "///...."? It makes my program really slow.

Comment: The reason why it's so slow, IMO has nothing to do with Base64 encoding. To answer your question, wikipedia explains quite clearly how it works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 
That said, the reason why it is slow is because, first you convert from PNG to BMP (conversion takes time), that converted byte[] also expands a lot in size, then by encoding that to base64 it will expand again to around double of what the BMP size is. If your purpose is only to send the image to a base64 string, then you should directly send the image without converting it to BMP first.